# Python scikit regression PCA on faces

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, pca

I have a dataset with faces showing the emotion happy. Every image has a percentage (integer values) of how happy the face is, ranging from 0-100% (0 being neutral and 100 maximum happy). I would like to apply PCA on this to reduce the dimensionality to later on apply machine learning, but I'm wondering how I should approach this.

**my code so far:**

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

folder = os.path.join('..','data','diff_face_s')


#Holds per emotion the data
class diffPCA():
    def __init__(self, emo):
        self.emo = emo
        self.data = np.empty([1,270,270], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.pers = [0]
        self.perc = [0]
        #PCA
        self.pca = PCA(n_components = 2)

    #Add flattened image    
    def process(self, img, pers, perc):
        #img: diff_face, pers: person, perc: percentage
        img_raw = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, img), 0)
        img_flat = img_raw.flatten()
        self.data = np.vstack(img_flat)
        self.pers.append(pers)
        self.perc.append(perc)

    def doPCA(self):
        self.pca.fit(self.data)

    def printPCA(self):
        print(self.pca.explained_variance_ratio_)


#Emotions
happy = diffPCA(1)

for img in os.listdir(folder):
    print(img)
    #name
    #perc
    #pers
    #if name starts with 1:
    happy.process(img, perc, pers)

happy.doPCA()
happy.printPCA()
```

**Questions:**

What is the best approach to reduce the dimensionality of the images based on the percentage? Can I just make a target list with percentages? Do I have 100 classes (1 for every percentage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example from the gallery](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html) may be helpful to obtain an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is indeed helpful for writing the code. However I was more looking for a theoretical answer if this is the right approach. Because I only have 1 class (happy) or I have 100 classes (0, 1, 2...100%). Would it work on so many classes or can I somehow say that it should work on a value instead of class?

Comment: Ah! Well don't do 100 classes, because there is structure in that variable. In essence it is a regression problem. But I don't think you'll get any satisfactory results by just applying linear regression (or PCA for that matter), because these will operate in pixel space. You should thus first extract features such as gabor energy or why not a later layer of a neural network as can be done with sklearn-theano.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll check it out. Any other information is welcome as well.